# JS $('form').change(function() only triggers on first form item

Tags: php, javascript, html

Following on from my question yesterday, I now have the code below somewhat successfully working. It allows me to change the first form item and submits it to 'process.php' in the background and turns the field green. However the trigger only works on the first form item, in this case "cstate". It doesn't trigger when "clocation" is changed. If you change clocation and then cstate then both form submit fine so it's simply that the .change function isn't triggering when clocation is changed. I'm not good enough at JS (total JS noob) to know why it isn't working so I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks!

```
 $sql = "select * from `$table1`";
 $result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 { 
   $carid = $row["car_id"]; 
   $carnum = $row["carnum"]; 
   $carlocation = $row["carlocation"];
   $carstate = $row["carstate"];


  $formname = "#form".$carid;

  print '<script type="text/javascript">';
  print "        var cnum;";
  print "        cnum = '$formname',";
  print "        

  $('form').change(function() 
  {
  console.log(cnum);
  $.ajax({ 
  type: 'post',
  url: 'process.php',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function() {
  }
   });
  return false;
   }); 
  </script>";

   echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr id='$carid'>";
   echo "<td>$carnum</td>";
   echo "<td><form action='' method='post' id='form$carid'>";
   echo "<select id='popup' name='cstate'>";
   echo "<option value='In-Service-Bay'>In Service Bay</option>";
   echo "<option value='Awaiting-Service'>Awaiting Service</option>";
   echo "<option value='Service-Complete'>Service Complete</option>";
   echo "</select></td>";
   echo "<select id='popup' name='clocation'>";
   echo "<option value='Carpark-1'>Carpark-1</option>";
   echo "<option value='Carpark-2'>Carpark-2</option>";
   echo "<option value='Carpark-3'>Carpark-3</option>";
   echo "</select></td>";
   echo "</form></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: your two selects have the same id. I guess it is what is causing your problem.

Comment: Tried them with different ID's, still the same problem.

Comment: and your html is not valid you are closing your form between td and tr ( should be in td )

Comment: @jbl may be code inside while loop causing it....right..?

Comment: @DipeshParmar I would for example have written $('#form$carid').change ... and performed it on document.ready . Anyway not sure I grasp the logic (the js located outside the loop should have been better design anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using a separate form for each input selection. Works brilliantly now.

Thanks to all those that tried to help.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()` and wrap code inside `document.ready.`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').on('submit',function() 
  {
     //code here
  });
});
```

also put this code outside the `while` loop. Also form does not have change event try using `.submit()`

Comment: Seems to work exactly the same as the above code. Still doesn't update when the second field is changed.

Comment: @Adam i am wondering if form have change event...replace `change` to `submit` and see.